# Can not create media folder in Django Project

Tags: python, django, django-models, file-upload, web-frameworks

Media folder is not getting created when I run the server. I am working in `localhost`.

You can see the urls.py and settings.py code below.

I added '`django.template.context_processors.media`' to the templates. My Django Version is 2.0.3 and I am using Python 3.6.8.

When I run the code, media folder should be created automatically. How can I fix that issue?

```
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media') #settings.py

    urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name = "index"),
    path('about/', views.about, name = "about"),
    path('articles/', include("article.urls")),
    path('user/', include("user.urls")),

 ] 

   urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) #urls.py
```

Comment: Can you try doing it like mentioned in docs? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development.
Instead of using `urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`. Also make sure to do the imports.

Comment: I tried to apply it like the DOC mentioned, but it didn't work. The media folder is still not getting created when I try to upload an image to an article via ckeditor with clicking the upload button on the form.

Comment: Have you tried uploading some file yet, if not try and tell what happens?

Comment: Please update your answer because I can not access your file.

Comment: I tried to upload as I mentioned above but When I click the upload button, I get that article is successfully created notif. that I made. However, media folder is not getting created.

Answer (score 1):

For a media file to be created,you need to add a slash after 'media' in the MEDIA_ROOT

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

instead of:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```